# The best synonym for "partition" in this sentence

Tags: word-choice

I have a network. I want to divide this network into several domains. The first version of this sentence that I have written is like this:

> The network is **partitioned** into several domains.

I want to rewrite this sentence and use another verb instead of "partition". I have looked for the synonyms and I have found "segregate" and "divide". I want to know which one can exactly convey the meaning here? Or is there any other alternative.

Comment: **"segmented"** sounds more fitting, I guess..?

Comment: It really depends what is meant, and whether the divisions are just administrative conveniences with no relation to how the system works, or represent significant divides (either physical or through firewalls, gateways, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible alternatives to **partitioned**:

- Your initial choice of ***divide*** (to separate into groups or parts or sections) is perfectly serviceable.
- If you're intending to convey distance between the various domains, you may wish to use the word ***separate*** (to keep apart or divide).
- @user108119 has a suggestion of ***segment*** (to separate or divide into segments) that would also work, with an implication that these are elements that have natural subdivisions.

That being said, your original word choice of ***partition*** is perfectly reasonable as it implies logical subdivisions, so you may not wish to use a different word in the first place.